# Failed to create spark session

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive

I'm trying to create spark session with the following configurations to create iceberg table , But failing to create the session with hive support. It would be great if anyone help me out with a solution. I'm literally stuck!

code:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.set("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions");
        conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog");
        conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type", "hive");
        conf.set("spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083");
        conf.set("spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "s3a://warehouse/");
        conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "true");
        conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true");
        conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "https://s3-endpoint");
        conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "access");
        conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "secret");
        conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.attempts.maximum", "1");
        conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.establish.timeout", "500");
        conf.set("spark.hadoop.datanucleus.autoCreateSchema", "true");
        conf.set("spark.hadoop.datanucleus.fixedDatastore", "false");
        
//      SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().appName("spark-test").master("local[*]").config(conf)
//              .getOrCreate();
        
           SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                    .builder()
                    .appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
                    .master("local[*]")
                    .config(conf)
                    .enableHiveSupport()
                    .getOrCreate();
```

Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because Hive classes are not found.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.enableHiveSupport(SparkSession.scala:865)
    at com.msi.spark.Main.main(Main.java:50)
```

Pom.xml

```
        <groupId>org.apache.iceberg</groupId>
        <artifactId>iceberg-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.iceberg</groupId>
        <artifactId>iceberg-spark3-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.iceberg</groupId>
          <artifactId>iceberg-parquet</artifactId>
          <version>0.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.iceberg</groupId>
          <artifactId>iceberg-hive</artifactId>
          <version>0.9.1</version>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: can you plz put the full exception message ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because Hive classes are not found.
 at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.enableHiveSupport(SparkSession.scala:865)
 at com.msi.spark.Main.main(Main.java:50)

Comment: I've added the follwoing dependency. 
``` <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>```

Comment: Now the exception is different:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void scala.Function1.$init$(scala.Function1)'
 at org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions.<init>(IcebergSparkSessionExtensions.scala:35)

Comment: Make sure you are using 2.12 scala dependencies and remove Spark3-extensions dependency since you're not using Spark3